# pytelegrambotapi, @bot.callback_query_handler выдает непонятную ошибку

Tags: python, функции, telegram-bot, telebot

Выдает непонятную ошибку, функция act3 не может принимать два значения, но как сделать так, чтобы код заработал? Уже долго не могу понять как, помогите плиз

```
def act2(message):
global temp
key = message.text
user_id = message.from_user.id
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for i in range(temp, temp + 10):
    markup.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{track[i]} - {artist[i]}', callback_data=f'btn{i}')
    )
nextbtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('➡️', callback_data='next')
backbtn = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅️', callback_data='back')
markup.add(backbtn, nextbtn, row_width=2)
bot.send_message(user_id, f'{key}:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def act3(call, message):
    global temp
    if call.data == 'next':
        temp += 10
        act2(message)
```

Вот сам код ошибки:

```
  File "D:/pythonProject/main.py", line 87, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "D:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 637, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "D:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 699, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "D:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 659, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "D:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 130, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "D:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 82, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: act3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Answer (score 0):

Сообщение об ошибке говорит вам, что в функцию `act3` не был передан аргумент `message`. Обработчик всегда будет передавать ей только `call`, а объект `message` нужно извлечь самому:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def act3(call):
    global temp
    if call.data == 'next':
        temp += 10
        act2(call.message)
```